# Evaluate OpenGL versio nthat is available to Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5, qt5.5

I want to find out which OpenGL version is available on my system for Qt. I know there is a native OpenGL get-version-string function available which returns this information but it is useless when working with OpenGL using Qt (because Qt has some ugly bugs which sometimes lead to the situation that OpenGL is not detected/initialised properly).

So: is there a Qt-function/-class/-whatever available which can be used to retrieve the current OpenGL version (or what Qt thinks the current OpenGL version is)?

Thanks :-)

Comment: OpenGLVersionFlags QGLFormat::openGLVersionFlags()
Identifies, at runtime, which OpenGL versions that are supported by the current platform.

Comment: ManuelH: thanks ,this looks good. But where can I find it? Qt-Doc says #include <QGLFormat> but it is #include <QtOpenGL/qgl.h>, Qt-Doc says link against "opengl" but this is also not correct...

Comment: OK, got it working - thanks!